# webjars -> HTTP 406

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, webjars

I am creating a very basic little web application using Spring Boot, thymeleaf and webjars.

What I want:
include jquery and bootstrap using webjars

What I did:
I included the dependencies into my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I added the jquery to my template index.html:

```
<script src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Problem: Although the thymeleaf jars are in my /lib directory and everything looks correct for me, it does not work. The HTML file shown in the browser shows the script line, but trying to fetch the jquery library directly (click on source in Chrome browser) ends up to a HTTP 406 error, while the path is shown as `http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js`:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Oct 17 09:34:32 CEST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you configure the WebMVC?

[Here](http://spring.io/blog/2014/01/03/utilizing-webjars-in-spring-boot) you can find an introduction how to use webjars with Spring WebMVC.

Comment: Thank you, your hint solved my issue. I did just use the annotation EnableAutoConfiguration, so I added the annotation EnableWebMcv and it works. The introduction is one of the first search results, so I knew it already (would have been a shame if not).

Comment: If you `EnableWebMvc` you switch off all the MVC defaults from Spring Boot. Fine if that's what you want, but I wouldn't do it that way. It works for me out of the box with `/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` so the 406 is probably caused by something else you did.